# Problema para manipular blob

Tags: php, base-de-datos, blob

es mi primer pregunta aca, si algo esta mal o falta info les pido que me avisen asi lo corrijo.

Explicación:

Estoy buscando pasar imágenes de sql en blob a una carpeta en el servidor en jpeg y que el nombre de estas sea el id de la base de datos.

```
while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        $directorio ="/fotos/";
        $aleatorio = $fila['id'];
        $ruta = "/fotos/".$aleatorio.".jpg";
        $nombre=$fila['imagenes']['name'];
        $guardado=$fila['imagenes']['tmp_name'];
        if(!file_exists($directorio)){
            mkdir($directorio ,0777,true);
            if(file_exists($directorio )){
                if(move_uploaded_file($guardado, 'archivos/'.$nombre)){
                    echo "Archivo guardado con exito";
                }else{
                    $contador++;
                    echo "Archivo guardado con exito - cantidad ",$contador;
                }
            }
        }else{
            if(move_uploaded_file($guardado, $directorio.$aleatorio.".jpg")){
                $contador++;
                echo "Archivo guardado con exito - cantidad ",$contador;
            }elseif(move_uploaded_file($guardado, $directorio.$aleatorio.".jpg")){
                $contador++;
                echo "Archivo guardado con exito - cantidad ",$contador;
            }else{
                echo "Archivo no se pudo guardar";
            }
            var_dump($ruta);
        }
    }
```

Es el ultimo código que estoy tratando, pero sin resultados, cuando arranca el while se muere.

Actualizado:

Ya lo conseguí con

```
file_put_contents('./imagenes/'.$id.'.jpg', $pic);
```

Espero que a alguien le sirva.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Mil disculpas, ahí edite la pregunta.

Comment: `fetch_assoc()` regresa un arreglo unidimensional, mientras intentas leerlo como si fuera bidimensional `$fila['imagenes']['name']`. ¿Cómo debería ser? no sabemos porque desconocemos la consulta y la estructura del resultado.